# Can I set up an auto backup function from one external hard drive to another?

Tags: hard-drive, mac, partitioning, backup, external-hard-drive

My external hard drive is partitioned with half as the location for my Mac Timemachine backups, and half as additional storage - mainly for large files that I don't have space for on my Mac (videos, images, and old archives I don't need regular access to).  (I'm on a 2012 Macbook Pro)

I have a 2nd external hard drive also used as a destination for Timemachine, and also partitioned the same way.

Is there a way that I can set up a cloning / auto backup function that would copy the additional storage portion on 1st disk and copy it to 2nd, if they're both plugged into the Mac?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider *Carbon Copy Cloner* or *SuperDuper* (or the like) for such a task where you can make easy selections what to copy where, setup scheduling etc. Everything will then be copied as soon as all devices appear.